# How to use the 'options' of bootstrap-fileupload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

How to use the 'options' of bootstrap-fileupload?

Options Documentation:

```
Name: uploadtype
type: string    
Description: Choose 'file' or 'image'. If omitted, the type is automatically determined based on the presence of a .thumbnail element.

Name: name
type: string
Description: Use this option instead of setting the name attribute on the <input> element to prevent it from being part of the post data when not changed.
```

Example?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Jasny Bootstrap.

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({'uploadtype':'image', 'name':'yourFieldName'});
```